# Ionic 3 Directive not working with ionic2-autosize

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I am using Ionic, and have a [`ion-textarea`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/) i would like to auto size, i.e. expand as the user adds more text.  I have found [`ionic2-autosize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-autosize), which is a `directive`. However, I cannot seem to make this `directive` have any effect on my [`ion-textarea`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/), i.e. it does not expand as the user adds more text.

I run:

```
npm install --save ionic2-autosize
```

**package.json**

```
"ionic2-autosize": "^1.1.1",
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Autosize} from 'ionic2-autosize';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp, Autosize
  ],
...
```

**review.ts**

```
<ion-textarea autosize [(ngModel)]="ratingModel.review" formControlName="review" id="review"></ion-textarea>
```

As you can see, I add the `autosize` attribute to the `ion-textarea`, but this has no effect, it behaves like a regular `ion-textarea` with only a height of 2 lines. I would expect the height to expand dynamically.

Any help appreciated.

**More info:**

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
    Cordova CLI      : 6.4.0 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

**UPDATE**

I add the `AutosizeModule` to my module:

**review.module.ts**

```
import {AutosizeModule} from 'ionic2-autosize';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReviewPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(ReviewPage), ControlMessagesModule, RatingComponentUpdateableModule, AutosizeModule],
  exports: [ReviewPage]
})
export class ReviewPageModule { }
```

But get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type Autosize is part of
>   the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and AutosizeModule! Please
>   consider moving Autosize to a higher module that imports AppModule and
>   AutosizeModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
>   includes Autosize then import that NgModule in AppModule and
>   AutosizeModule.

**UPDATE**

I removed it from the `app.module.ts`, and it seems to have fixed the above error.  However, now I get:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already
>   been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and
>   NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead. Error:
>   BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common
>   directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import
>   CommonModule instead.

**UPDATE**

Rather used `CommonModule`:

**review.module.ts**

```
//import {AutosizeModule} from 'ionic2-autosize';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReviewPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(ReviewPage), ControlMessagesModule, RatingComponentUpdateableModule, CommonModule],
  exports: [ReviewPage]
})
export class ReviewPageModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AutosizeModule } from 'ionic2-autosize';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    BrowserModule,
    AutosizeModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

The errors went away, but the `ion-textarea` still does not autosize.

Comment: Hi Pengyy, nope I haven't. Where do I get `AutosizeModule` from? I was not aware I had to import it? Is it part of `ionic2-autosize`?

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand, however, please see my UPDATE above. I added the `AutosizeModule`, but am getting an error.

Comment: Thanks, I now replaced `AutosizeModule` with `CommonModule` in my `review.module.ts`. I now get no errors. But I am back to square one, the `ion-textarea` does not autosize.

Comment: Nope, but I have just added `AutosizeModule` back to `app.module.ts`, and there is no errors, but also no autosizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a pull request on his git and hopefully he'll fix it.
All you need to do for this to work is to remove BrowserModule.

The BrowserModule is needed for projects that are the whole project. 
Small NgModules if need be(ngIf, ngFor, ngClass, etc) require CommonModule.

In Ionic3 its a rule that only the top most @NgModule will have the BrowserModule.

For reference
https://github.com/misha130/ionic2-autosize/commit/3b40925dca104ec76fe55b4af3a726efb7e3efbe

Comment: Thanks, but if I remove `BrowserModule` from `app.module.ts`, I get: `ERROR Error: No provider for ApplicationInitStatus!`. I even tried adding `CommonModule` to `app.module.ts`, but I still get the error.

Comment: Not your browsermodule. His. This is why I made a pull request. His library has a problem

Comment: Okay, sorry I misunderstood. So it's looks like `ionic2-autosize` is not compatible with Ionc3 for now. Thanks, I will try another library.

Comment: Yes take the my git fork url and stick it instead of the version number in package.json.

Comment: I just tested with the package, and it works as expected.  are you sure what you figured is right?

Comment: @Pengyy I have my own ionic library too and this happened to me too.

Comment: @misha130 I just build a simple app with ionic 3.1.2 and don't have any problem.

Comment: @pengyy are you using 2 ngmodules and @ionicpage?

Comment: @misha130, to use your forked version, do I need to update my `package.json` and run `npm install`?  What do I update the `package.json` with?

Comment: Update it to "ionic2-autosize":"git://github.com/misha130/ionic2-autosize" and npm install. Maybe the author will just accept the pull request.

Comment: @Pengyy https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module See "BrowserModule throws error with lazy loading"

Comment: @misha130 isn't this error caused by importing `AutosizeModule` in submodules?

Comment: @Pengyy AutosizeModule imports BrowserModule

Comment: @misha130 I know this.  but you can just import it at `AppModule`.

Comment: But if you import it in AppModule you cant lazyload pages with autosize directive since they dont recognize it.

Comment: @misha130, thanks, I updated my `package.json` as you suggest, then run `npm install`, but I get: `misha130/ionic2-autosize‌​ is not a valid repository name`

Comment: It works for me but I tested to see and it seems npm doesnt want TS in its node_modules. So it doesn't work anyway if you do npm it. If you really really want to just copy paste it in your project and thats it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am going to try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-elastic.  Tested this, and it works perfectly.  Thanks for the help though.